# Weblogic, does setDomainEnv.sh classpath and java arguments inherit to managed server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, weblogic, classpath

I set `PRE_CLASSPATH`, `POST_CLASSPATH` and `EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES` environment variables in `setDomainEnv.sh` script file.

When I create a new *machine* and a new *server* in the admin console and target this new server to the new machine, does it inherit the classpath and java properties from the domain, or do I have to repeat them in server start arguments.

If they inherit, how can I override or disable them?

Answer (score 0):

The `setDomainEnv.sh` is executed when you start up the Managed Server.

You have multiple options that you can choose to set the same parameters (i.e. Memory Arguments) across all managed servers:

1. You can create a file named `setUserOverrides.sh` where you can set the variables that `setDomainEnv.sh` script uses that you want to set. This way, you don't have to modify the `setDomainEnv.sh` at all. I have created domains in WebLogic 12.1.3 and I see that this file exists in the `$DOMAIN_HOME/bin` directory, so you're in luck if you are using 12c. Otherwise you can inject the following code in `setDomainEnv.sh` to call `setUserOverrides.sh` at runtime (make sure that the script has the appropriate execute permissions):

   ```
   if [ -f ${DOMAIN_HOME}/bin/setUserOverrides.sh ] ; then
       . ${DOMAIN_HOME}/bin/setUserOverrides.sh
   fi
   ```
2. You can use Server Templates to set a generic Server parameters. When you set the Server Template for the Managed Server, it will inherit the parameters set in the Server Template. With this, you can override the Server template parameters by going to the Managed Server and changing the parameter values from there.
3. You can always edit the `setDomainEnv.sh` to include your parameter value declarations. Make sure to put in the file on the `$DOMAIN_HOME/bin` folder on the other machine.

References:

- [Customizing Domain Wide Server Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/START/overview.htm#START250)
- [Server Templates](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/DOMCF/server_templates.htm#DOMCF200)